# Can I save/load multiple keras neural network models into one .h5 file?

Tags: python, keras

I trained 5 neural network models and want to share with my teammates. I don't want to save them one by one to 5 .h5 models. Is there any way that I can save them into one .h5 file?

Here is how I save/load one model to one file.

```
# save the entire model
model.save('model.h5')    # model is a trained keras model.

# load the saved model
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, Keras doesn't have this functionality.

Comment: Instead save each of the models as a .h5 file. Then, zip these 5 files together to create one zip file. Or, create a array of your models and pickle the array in a .pkl file.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I will try the zip option. Keras model cannot be pickled, so I don't think I can store them in a list/array and pickle them

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro That's sad.

Comment: Keras models can be pickled since Keras 2.2.3, see the release notes: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.2.3

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro That is great! Thank you for the update!